# Restricting user to invoke package procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace package p is
  function f1 return number;
  function f2 return number;
  procedure p1;
end p;
/
create or replace package body p is
  function f1 return number is begin return 1; end;
  function f2 return number is begin return 2; end;
  procedure p1 is begin null; end;
  procedure p2 is begin null; end;
end p;
/
```

In above example p2 cant be invoked from outside the package, either f1,f2 or p1 can call p2, this I m aware of. However, if I want to restrict p1 the same way.

**Catch here is I cant remove p1 from package specification either.**

It was interview question and tried to google it out but didn't find solution  for this. Looking out if this is possible and if yes then how.

Comment: Other than removing from spec, I don't know how that is possible.

Comment: Maybe wrapping the p1's inside code within a conditional, to execute just for a specific user: something like: `procedure p1 is begin if (USER='ADMIN') then null; end if; end;` However this wouldn't prevent p1 from being invoked, it just restricts it's code execution.

Comment: Maybe they were looking for Oracle 12C [whitelists](http://tkyte.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/12c-whitelists.html)?

Comment: @TonyAndrews I think this is the answer

Comment: don't give user access to 'Execute' anything :) Something like `revoke execute on p ...`

Comment: @Tony Andrews - can you mention whitelist in answer so that I can mark it as correct one, this seems to be closest what I was looking for.

Comment: @PravinSatav - done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They may have been wanting you to mention the concept of [whitelists](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/packages.htm#LNPLS00902) introduced in Oracle 12C.  This is implemented by a new `ACCESSIBLE BY` clause, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE mypackage
  ACCESSIBLE BY (yourpackage)
IS
  PROCEDURE p1;
END;
```

Here any procedures or functions in package `mypackage` can only be called from `mypackage` itself or from the whitelisted program unit `yourpackage` specified in the `ACCESSIBLE BY` clause.

There is some good detail on this topic [in this Oracle-Base article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/plsql-white-lists-using-the-accessible-by-clause-12cr1).